# Does this inequality have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

> $$\int_{B_R} f \leq C \int_{B_R} \left(\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} f(y) dy \right)$$
>   where $f \geq 0$, $R \geq 0$, and $B_R \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a ball of radius $R$. The above should hold for $r \in (0, R).$

Comment: Is this from Apostol?